# Error while importing selenium even though selenium is installed

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm working on a project to learn web scraping. I've been coding pretty actively since March with no import issues, but yesterday I tried to run:
`from selenium import webdriver`
and I was met with:

```
  line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

When I run `pip3 list` I can see `selenium   3.141.0`, so I don't understand the issue. I've tried to fix it for the last hour and a half, but no working solutions found. It's not an issue with my IDE (I've tried it in different code editors and been met with the same error). I've uninstalled and re-installed selenium many different ways, so I'm really stuck. I can always use Scrapy or some other web scraping module, but if this can be fixed that would be great! I'm on Mac OS and python 3.8, any idea is helpful, thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed?

Comment: You can type ```where python``` in ```cmd``` if you are on windows to see how many python instances you have and where are they stored on your computer. Then check if the interpreter being used by your text-editor is the same as the one where you installed selenium.

Comment: As a beginner it is generally not recommended to have more than one instance of python installed.